# Append values to query string

Tags: c#, parameters, query-string

I have set of URLs similar to the ones below in a list

- `http://somesite.example/backup/lol.php?id=1&server=4&location=us`
- `http://somesite.example/news.php?article=1&lang=en`

I have managed to get the query strings using the following code:

```
myurl = longurl.Split('?');
NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myurl [1]);

foreach (string lol in qs)
{
    // results will return
}
```

But it only returns the parameters like
**id**, **server**, **location** and so on based on the URL provided.

What I need is to add / append values to the existing query strings.

For example with the URL:

`http://somesite.example/backup/index.php?action=login&attempts=1`

I need to alter the values of the query string parameters:

**action=login1**

**attempts=11**

As you can see, I have appended "1" for each value. I need to get a set of URLs from a string with different query strings in them and add a value to each parameter at the end & again add them to a list.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

You could use the [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method and an [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) which provides a nice way to work with query string parameters without worrying about things like parsing, URL encoding, ...:

```
string longurl = "http://somesite.example/news.php?article=1&lang=en";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["action"] = "login1";
query["attempts"] = "11";
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
longurl = uriBuilder.ToString();
// "http://somesite.example:80/news.php?article=1&lang=en&action=login1&attempts=11"
```

Comment: I Think you have misunderstood the question, what i exactly need do is to append values to existing paramers. in this case **longurl** should return **"http://somesite.com/news.php?article=11&lang=en1";**

the parameters are dynamic as well. they are always not **action** or **attempts**

Comment: As you can see from my example you could use variable names for the parameters. And that's exactly what it does: it appends 2 parameters to the existing url that I have hardcoded here but they could perfectly fine be dynamic.

Comment: I just got the query strings with a loop since **query** is a list. Is their a better way ? and how can i add the values to strings .. im a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: Yeah you could get all query string parameters in a loop using my approach: `foreach (string key in query.AllKeys) { var value = query[key]; }`.

Comment: I've already covered the part of adding query string parameters in my answer: `query["myCustomKey"] = "my custom value";`

Comment: Yeah, I used a forloop with **query.count** :-) .. Thanks You Darin

Comment: Shouldn't we use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` when assigning parameter value?

Comment: @UserControl, no, the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method returns a special NameValueCollection implementation which already handles this behind the scenes when you set a value.

Comment: Bummer that this has a dependency on System.Web :/

Comment: it is worth noting that this approach can cause issues with internationalization as special characters will be converted to their unicode equivalents in the query.ToString() method.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this solution does not work with relative Uri's. See my answer below for more information.

Comment: @tezromania: Actually it doesn't break i18n (how can Unicode break i18n? duh). It just [uses a non-standard URI encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1825657/236871). It seems that ParseQueryString uses UrlEncodeUnicode() (which is already deprecated) and the resulting URI is not accepted in some browsers.

Comment: If you want to avoid the reliance on `System.Web`, you can use the extensions provided [here](https://github.com/xamarin/PortableRazor/blob/master/PortableRazor.Web/HttpUtility.cs)

Comment: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` returns `HttpValueCollection` which is not public class and implements `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It does some of the encoding for my values, but what about the ISO date format which has + chars. It left them as + chars - I need them to be converted to %2B. Please could you help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 147):

I've wrapped [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14517976) into a nicely reusable extension method.

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified parameter to the Query String.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    /// <param name="paramName">Name of the parameter to add.</param>
    /// <param name="paramValue">Value for the parameter to add.</param>
    /// <returns>Url with added parameter.</returns>
    public static Uri AddParameter(this Uri url, string paramName, string paramValue)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query[paramName] = paramValue;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to add multiple parameters with the same key(ie `a=1&a=2&a=3`).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - In what situation would you ever want to use the same parameter names in a single call?

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ while old, still applies.

Comment: You can use `query.Add(paramName, paramValue)`  to allow multiple parameters with the same key.

Comment: url = url.AddParameter(paramName, paramValue); if you using Brinkie's code

Comment: It's better to extend (and return) UriBuilder then Uri

Answer (score 61):

The provided answers have issues with relative URLs, such as "/some/path/"
This is a limitation of the URI and UriBuilder class, which is rather hard to understand, since I don't see any reason why relative URLs would be problematic when it comes to query manipulation.

Here is a workaround that works for both absolute and relative paths, written and tested in .NET 4:

(small note: this should also work in .NET 4.5, you will only have to change `propInfo.GetValue(values, null)` to `propInfo.GetValue(values)`)

```
  public static class UriExtensions{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds query string value to an existing url, both absolute and relative URI's are supported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>
    ///     // returns "www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2&amp;param3=val3"
    ///     new Uri("www.domain.example/test?param1=val1").ExtendQuery(new Dictionary&lt;string, string&gt; { { "param2", "val2" }, { "param3", "val3" } });
    ///
    ///     // returns "/test?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2&amp;param3=val3"
    ///     new Uri("/test?param1=val1").ExtendQuery(new Dictionary&lt;string, string&gt; { { "param2", "val2" }, { "param3", "val3" } });
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Uri ExtendQuery(this Uri uri, IDictionary<string, string> values) {
      var baseUrl = uri.ToString();
      var queryString = string.Empty;
      if (baseUrl.Contains("?")) {
        var urlSplit = baseUrl.Split('?');
        baseUrl = urlSplit[0];
        queryString = urlSplit.Length > 1 ? urlSplit[1] : string.Empty;
      }

      NameValueCollection queryCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
      foreach (var kvp in values ?? new Dictionary<string, string>()) {
        queryCollection[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
      }
      var uriKind = uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? UriKind.Absolute : UriKind.Relative;
      return queryCollection.Count == 0
        ? new Uri(baseUrl, uriKind)
        : new Uri(string.Format("{0}?{1}", baseUrl, queryCollection), uriKind);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds query string value to an existing url, both absolute and relative URI's are supported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>
    ///     // returns "www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2&amp;param3=val3"
    ///     new Uri("www.domain.example/test?param1=val1").ExtendQuery(new { param2 = "val2", param3 = "val3" });
    ///
    ///     // returns "/test?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2&amp;param3=val3"
    ///     new Uri("/test?param1=val1").ExtendQuery(new { param2 = "val2", param3 = "val3" });
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Uri ExtendQuery(this Uri uri, object values) {
      return ExtendQuery(uri, values.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary
      (
          propInfo => propInfo.Name,
          propInfo => { var value = propInfo.GetValue(values, null); return value != null ? value.ToString() : null; }
      ));
    }
  }
```

And here is a suite of unit tests to test the behavior:

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class UriExtensionsTests {
    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_no_query_string_and_values_is_empty_should_return_url_without_changing_it() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test");
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_hash_and_query_string_values_are_empty_should_return_url_without_changing_it() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test#div");
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test#div")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_no_query_string_should_add_values() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test");
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param1", "val1" }, { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&param2=val2")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_hash_and_no_query_string_should_add_values() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test#div");
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param1", "val1" }, { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test#div?param1=val1&param2=val2")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_query_string_should_add_values_and_keep_original_query_string() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1");
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&param2=val2")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_is_relative_contains_no_query_string_should_add_values() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param1", "val1" }, { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=val1&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_is_relative_and_contains_query_string_should_add_values_and_keep_original_query_string() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test?param1=val1", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=val1&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_is_relative_and_contains_query_string_with_existing_value_should_add_new_values_and_update_existing_ones() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test?param1=val1", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "param1", "new-value" }, { "param2", "val2" } };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=new-value&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_object_when_url_contains_no_query_string_should_add_values() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test");
      var values = new { param1 = "val1", param2 = "val2" };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&param2=val2")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_object_when_url_contains_query_string_should_add_values_and_keep_original_query_string() {
      Uri url = new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1");
      var values = new { param2 = "val2" };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("http://www.domain.example/test?param1=val1&param2=val2")));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_object_when_url_is_relative_contains_no_query_string_should_add_values() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new { param1 = "val1", param2 = "val2" };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=val1&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_object_when_url_is_relative_and_contains_query_string_should_add_values_and_keep_original_query_string() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test?param1=val1", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new { param2 = "val2" };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=val1&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_to_query_string_object_when_url_is_relative_and_contains_query_string_with_existing_value_should_add_new_values_and_update_existing_ones() {
      Uri url = new Uri("/test?param1=val1", UriKind.Relative);
      var values = new { param1 = "new-value", param2 = "val2" };
      var result = url.ExtendQuery(values);
      Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Uri("/test?param1=new-value&param2=val2", UriKind.Relative)));
    }
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work for ASP.NET 5 using cloud .NET as HttpUtility does not seem to be available. But it's a great solution otherwise. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-dnx

Comment: "Add_to_query_string_dictionary_when_url_contains_hash_and_no_query_string_should_add_values" should test that the URL becomes http://www.domain.com/test?param1=val1&param2=val2#div

Comment: Please counter check, whether you're not better off using `uri.AbsoluteUri` instead of `uri.ToString()` because of nasty un-escaping effects.

Comment: Addition: `uri.AbsoluteUri` throws, if the uri is not absolute!

Answer (score 47):

Note you can add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` nuget package from Microsoft and then use this to append values to query string:

```
QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(longurl, "action", "login1")
QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(longurl, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "action", "login1" }, { "attempts", "11" } });
```

Comment: As of ASP.NET Core 3.0 WebUtilities is now part of the ASP.NET SDK so no nuget package needed.

Comment: The problem with `AddQueryString` is that it will always add, if there is already the key, it won't update, but create duplicate keys, with is bad

Comment: @Vencovsky But you can check if it exists using `QueryHelpers.ParseQuery`

Comment: @Vencovsky I disagree;, why would you do multiple passes with different values of the same parameter on the same query string?

Comment: @Vencovsky: *"it won't update, but create duplicate keys, with is bad"* On the contrary: Duplicate keys are perfectly valid in query strings.

Answer (score 17):

The following solution works for ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and it uses QueryHelpers class to build a URI with parameters.

```
    public Uri GetUri()
    {
        var location = _config.Get("http://iberia.com");
        Dictionary<string, string> values = GetDictionaryParameters();

        var uri = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(location, values);
        return new Uri(uri);
    }

    private Dictionary<string,string> GetDictionaryParameters()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "param1", "value1" },
            { "param2", "value2"},
            { "param3", "value3"}
        };
        return values;
    }
```

The result URI would have `http://iberia.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`

Comment: The only problem with using a Dictionary as the store for query keys and values is that query strings can have duplicate keys with different values. I believe that a request to an ASP.NET site parses that as an array of values for that one key.

Answer (score 2):

I like Bjorn's answer, however the solution he's provided is misleading, as the method updates an existing parameter, rather than adding it if it doesn't exist.. To make it a bit safer, I've adapted it below.

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds or Updates the specified parameter to the Query String.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    /// <param name="paramName">Name of the parameter to add.</param>
    /// <param name="paramValue">Value for the parameter to add.</param>
    /// <returns>Url with added parameter.</returns>
    public static Uri AddOrUpdateParameter(this Uri url, string paramName, string paramValue)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

        if (query.AllKeys.Contains(paramName))
        {
            query[paramName] = paramValue;
        }
        else
        {
            query.Add(paramName, paramValue);
        }
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really made a marginal edit of the code, I didn't provide it (the OP did) ... what will the difference though?

Comment: The if / else is not necessary, just do `query[paramName] = paramValue;` in all cases. It it exists, it wil be overridden. If it not exists, the key wil be created.

Answer (score 2):

This is even more frustrating because now (.net 5) MS have marked many (all) of their methods that take a string instead of a `Uri` as obsolete.

Anyway, probably a better way to manipulate relative `Uri`s is to give it what it wants:

```
var requestUri = new Uri("x://x").MakeRelativeUri(
   new UriBuilder("x://x") { Path = path, Query = query }.Uri);
```

You can use the other answers to actually build the query string.

Answer (score 1):

### *The end to all URL query string editing woes*

After lots of toil and fiddling with the Uri class, and other solutions, here're my *string* extension methods to solve my problems.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string AddToQueryString(this string url, params object[] keysAndValues)
    {
        return UpdateQueryString(url, q =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < keysAndValues.Length; i += 2)
            {
                q.Set(keysAndValues[i].ToString(), keysAndValues[i + 1].ToString());
            }
        });
    }

    public static string RemoveFromQueryString(this string url, params string[] keys)
    {
        return UpdateQueryString(url, q =>
        {
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                q.Remove(key);
            }
        });
    }

    public static string UpdateQueryString(string url, Action<NameValueCollection> func)
    {
        var urlWithoutQueryString = url.Contains('?') ? url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf('?')) : url;
        var queryString = url.Contains('?') ? url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')) : null;
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString ?? string.Empty);

        func(query);

        return urlWithoutQueryString + (query.Count > 0 ? "?" : string.Empty) + query;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd discourage people from using raw `string`s to represent URLs like this considering the `Uri` class already exists for that purpose. Either use that, or create a brand new abstraction if features are missing.