# URL unicode parameters decoding C#

Tags: c#, url, unicode

I got a URL which contains parameters, one of which is with Cyrillic letters.

> http://localhost/Print.aspx?id=4&subwebid=243572&docnumber=%u0417%u041f005637-1&deliverypoint=4630013519990

Doc-number must be **ЗП005637-1**.
I have tried the following code, but string is still with those characters *%u0417%u041f*.

```
public static String DecodeUrlString(this String url)
    {
        String newUrl;
        while ((newUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)) != url)
            url = newUrl;
        return newUrl;
    }
```

It's not a possibility to use HttpUtility.

Comment: So use the code *from* HttpUtility; http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,afac0d4e31f5382a

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to HttpUtility.ParseQueryString without System.Web dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442985/alternative-to-httputility-parsequerystring-without-system-web-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid a dependency on `System.Web.dll`, then you would normally use the equivalent method in the [WebUtility Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx): [WebUtility.UrlDecode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, you will find that, even then, your url won't get decoded the way you want it to.

This is because `WebUtility.UrlDecode` does not handle the `%uNNNN` escape notation on purpose.  Notice this comment in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/30f354addb9f56b3.html):

```
// *** Source: alm/tfs_core/Framework/Common/UriUtility/HttpUtility.cs
// This specific code was copied from above ASP.NET codebase.
// Changes done - Removed the logic to handle %Uxxxx as it is not standards compliant.
```

As stated in the comment, the `%uNNNN` escape format is not standard compliant and should be avoided if possible. You can find more info on this and on the proper way of encoding urls from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters).

If you have any control over how the url is generated, consider changing it to be standard-compliant.  Otherwise, consider adding `System.Web.dll` as a dependency, find another third-party library that does the job, or write your own decoder. As commented already, the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,afac0d4e31f5382a) is out there.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. `%uNNNN` is usually a sign that something on the client side is using the deprecated JavaScript `escape()` function. This doesn't produce valid URLs: not only does the `%u` escape come out for Unicode characters, but the `%` escapes for 0x80–0xFF are wrong too. So by far the best fix is to stop using `escape()` and go to `encodeURIComponent()` instead.